# How to identify if region_id is required or region (region_name) is required?

Tags: magento2, orders, customer-address

I am creating customer address in Magento 2 programatically.

In few countries the `region_id` is required, which can be obtained from the model `\Magento\Directory\Model\Region`, for example for`US` country and in few countries the `region` is required which is a text field, for example for `Italy` country.

How to identify if `region_id` is required or `region` (region_name) is required for the country?

Comment: You can check the country list under Store->Configuration->General->State Required for.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you. Take a look at `\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data`

```
public function getRegionData()
{
    .....
    return $regions;
}
```

This function will return the list of countries which have the regions are required.

You should build your own logic.